# Checking "rules" in Java without lots of if statements

Tags: java, spring-boot, if-statement

I'm creating a springboot banking API and in order to create a transaction a bunch of "rules" have to be checked.

e.g:

- Current logged in user can't withdraw money from another user's savings account
- Amount can't be higher/lower than certain number
- etc.

This causes my createTransaction method to contain a lot of if statements (12!). This is what my code looks like in pseudo:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> createTransaction(Transaction body) {
    if (check rule 1) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("...");
    }
    if (check rule 2) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("...");
    }
    // etc...

    // Transaction complies to set rules
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Transaction successful!");
}
```

I can post my actual code if necessary but I think this paints the picture without having anyone to read 100 lines of code.

Because I have around 12 if statements checking these rules, my function is quite lengthy and difficult to read/maintain.
Googling for a solution didn't bring up results I was looking for. I've tried implementing exceptions but this didn't remove the amount of if statements. Maybe a switch could improve a bit, but I'm wondering if there's a clean OOP solution.

My question is: How can I clean this code up (OOP style)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the thing you do after you check each rule:  `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("...");` always the same?

Comment: Could you add at least one rule to the question? Just checking its complexity. And describe which java version is able to use. E.g. In Java 14 the switch-case statement was improved a lot.

Comment: @Sweeper I return a BAD Request at pretty much each check (10/12) but each time the body is different to give the user correct feedback ("Incorrect amount", "This account doesn't exist", etc).

Comment: @zforgo I'm using Java 11, a couple of checks I do are:

Check if accounts don't equal each other, and make sure a user can't transfer money between Savings accounts (only Current->Savings and vice versa)

Not very complex checks but they have to be done since the frontend is in JS which forces me to check user input here.

Comment: @Stef are you effectively validating the input before you process it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `TransactionRule` interface that allows you to implement specific transaction rules, and then use a stream to get the final result:

```java
public interface TransactionRule {
  public boolean isAllowed(Transaction someTransaction);
}
```

Example implementation 1:

```java
public class SufficientBudgetTransactionRule implements TransactionRule {
  public boolean isAllowed(Transaction someTransaction) {
    // Custom logic e.g. 
    return someTransaction.wallet.value >= someTransaction.transaction.value;
  }
}
```

Example implementation 2:

```java
public class NotInFutureTransactionRule implements TransactionRule {
  public boolean isAllowed(Transaction someTransaction) {
    // Custom logic e.g. 
    return someTransaction.transaction.datetime.isBefore(OffsetDateTime.now());
  }
}
```

Then, you can store all the `TransactionRules` in a `List` and check whether they all validate like so:

```
private final List<TransactionRule> transactionRules; // Fill these of course

public boolean allTransactionRulesMatch(Transaction someTransaction) {
  return transactionRules.stream()
    .map(transactionRule -> transactionRule.isAllowed(someTransaction))
    .allMatch(result => result);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!